# MS Access Update Query where column updated depends on field in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (**InfoTable**) that I would like to update based on another table (**UpdTable**).  The UpdTable has three columns, *OldEntry*, *NewEntry*, and *UpdateField*.   **InfoTable** has columns that will match **UpdateField**.  I will have one line per update.  So, for example, UpdTable:

| OldEntry | NewEntry | UpdateField |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | Paul | Customer |
| 123khjiv | 3546sfdg | Serial Number |

I would like to feed a SQL query or SQL code that takes **UpdTable** and have it update **InfoTable**.  **InfoTable** has many columns, but I only want the columns in *UpdateField* modified.

I am trying to streamline this process since I am currently doing the updates one by one by hand.  At this time, I do not have any code written as I have been unable to formulate a working plan.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider looping through the records of *UpdTable* and pass values into a parameterized `UPDATE` query using DAO [Recordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-object-dao) and [QueryDef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-object-dao) objects:

```vb
Dim updRST As DAO.Recordset
Dim qDEF As DAO.QueryDef

' OPEN RECORDSET
Set updRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("UpdTable")
updRST.MoveFirst

' LOOP THROUGH RECORDS
Do While Not updRST.EOF
    ' PREPARED SQL STATEMENT
    sql = "PARAMETERS [new_val] TEXT, [old_val] TEXT; " _
        & "UPDATE InfoTable SET [" & updRST!UpdateField & "] = [new_val] " _
        & "WHERE [" & updRST!UpdateField & "] = [old_val]"

    Set qDEF = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", sql)
    qDEF!new_val = updRST!NewEntry                  ' BIND PARAMS
    qDEF!old_val = updRST!OldEntry

    qDEF.Execute dbFailOnError                      ' EXECUTE ACTION
    Set qDEF = Nothing

    updRST.MoveNext
Loop 

updRST.Close
Set updRST = Nothing
```

Comment: In Access there are a lot of ways to skin the cat of adding and editing records including adodb, dao, doCMD, the macro language, etc.  In this case, the approach I find most user friendly is to use the methods(AddNew, Edit, Insert) on the recordset object.  This approach bypasses writing sql.  see here for an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/modify-an-existing-record-in-a-dao-recordset

Comment: Indeed, @mazoula. This solution though opens one recordset and avoids `if` logic to find specific record. In fact, OP can even save the parameterized query as a stored object and never show SQL!

Comment: This looks really interesting! And with the addition of parameterized queries, I have a lot to learn.  The first field should have been “AssetNumber”, instead of “OldEntry” (too much time staring at my screen).  But your answer seems the same even with the change. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much, @Parfait!

For people looking at this, the only change I had to do was add “Set” in the beginning of line 5.